# Calculating terrain height in 3d-space

Tags: 3d

I'm diving into 3d programming a bit and am currently learning by writing a procedural terrain generator that generates terrain based on a heightmap. I would also want to implement some physics and my first attempt at terrain collision was by simply checking the current position vs the heightmap. This however wont work well against small objects  as you'd have to calculate the height by taking the heightdifference of the nearest vertices of the object and doing this every colision check is pretty slow.

Beleive me I tried googling for it but there's simply so much crap and millions of blogs posting ripped-of newbie tutorials everywhere with basically no real information on the subject, I can't find anything that explains it or even names any generally used techniques.

I'm not asking for code or a complete solution, but if anyone knows a particular technique good for calculating a high-res heightmap out of the already generated and smoothed terrain I would be very happy as I could look into it further when I know what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you made your terrain a group of quads based on those height positions combined with their x/y positions.  Now, store the normals for those quads.  Now, you are doing a simple, is this point on this side of the polygon check which is very quick to calculate - the sign of a dot product between the surface normal and the point you are checking against.  It's like back face culling and most 3D systems will have routines to handle this for you.

Comment: Not a bad idea, I'm going to look into it, gave me some ideas thanks :) I'll get back to it tomorrow when I've tested it.

Comment: Your suggetions surely led me in the right direction, thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend that you first start within a 2d world heightmap, then once you grasp how the heightmap works then program it in a 3D world.

This tutorial best describes what I mean.
http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/Terrain_from_file.php

Look into Unity also:
http://vimeo.com/73273585

Comment: No offense but this question was asked 4 years ago and it's already answered with a perfectly fine answer. Also starting out with a 2d world would not have helped as the question was regarding flexible and quick ways of calculating the height of one point in the map with high precision without slowing down the program. Not about rendering a terrain from a heightmap.